# Using overloaded output operator for templated class: Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading, output, undefined-symbol

I am playing around with a templated, array-based stack class and having trouble with overloading the output operator. To start, I have something like this:

```
template <typename Object>
class ArrayStack {
  public:

    ...

    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& _os, ArrayStack& _as);

    ...

  private:
    ...
    Object*   S;   // the stack array
    int       t;   // index of the top of the stack
};
```

Then, as a free function within the same file (ArrayStack.h), the output operator is implemented as follows:

```
template <typename Object>
ostream& 
operator<<(ostream& _os, ArrayStack<Object>& _as){

  for(int i = 0; i <= _as.t; i++){
    _os << (_as.S)[i] << '\n'; 
  }
  return _os;
}
```

I try to use this operator in the separate ASTest.cpp:

```
#include "ArrayStack.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){

  ArrayStack<int> intStack(10);
  intStack.push(12);
  intStack.push(3);
  cout << "The stack: " << endl;
  cout << intStack;  //Error! 
}
```

This fails to compile, with the following error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "operator<<(std::ostream&, ArrayStack<int>&)", referenced from:
      _main in ASPractice-rDD5cY.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

What is going wrong here? My guess is that something is looking for a very specific `<<` operator that is made for ArrayStacks of ints...and it isn't happy with the broad one that is templated for any old "Object", despite the fact that this should seemingly accommodate ints and just about anything else! (?)

How do I fix this?

In case it is important, here is the output of g++ -v on my Mac OS X 10.8.5:

```
Configured with: --prefix=/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 5.0 (clang-500.2.75) (based on LLVM 3.3svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin12.5.0
Thread model: posix
```